# How exactly do I pass a POST body parameter using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post

I'm trying to provide an "mfa-code" parameter to a post request using python requests, but the response I'm getting is that the parameter "mfa-code" is missing, even though I try and provide it via `requests.post(url, data={"mfa-code": "0000"})` and also tried `requests.post(url, json={"mfa-code": "0000"})`.

Here is what I'm trying to send.

```
POST /login2 HTTP/1.1
Host: redacted.net
Cookie: session=qexMWyQnLtSlBI8B005qnVW4OYvEwEV2; verify=wiener
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://redacted.net/login2
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 13
Origin: https://redacted.net
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Dnt: 1
Sec-Gpc: 1
Te: trailers
Connection: close

mfa-code=0000
```

And this is the request I'm sending with my python script

```
import requests

url = "redacted.net"
data={"mfa-code": "0000"}
r = reqeusts.post(url, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

This results in a response only stating:
"Missing parameter 'mfa-code'"

I took note in the response and how mfa-code is surrounded with ', so I went to burp repeater and put single quotes on mfa-code and sure enough received the same error.
I then tried with other options like json=json.dumps(data), but to the same result as the requests needs a POST body parameter of the type variable=data and not a json object.

What am I missing here?
Or is this something python requests cannot do?

Comment: Your code isn't sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content type.  Perhaps that is the issue.

Comment: Maybe try `r = requests.post(url, params={'mfa-code': '0000'})` since the error message says `Missing parameter 'mfa-code'`

Comment: @mama "params=" is a GET thing, doesn't really work with POST, but yes I also tried this in my desperation haha.

Comment: I added ```headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}``` and then modified my post request like this ```r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)```, but still the same result.